# Finding density of a thin plate

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image: d]

I found the bounds of the function as 0 < x < 2  and 0 < y < 4  and took the double integral of the density function over this interval and got an answer of  M = 24. I don't have an answer key so I'm not sure if I did something wrong or if the answer is correct and that it's " h. None of the above".

[image]

Comment: Can you type out your work for us to check?

Comment: @The Count I've attached my work.

Comment: It's not clear for me if you want the area below the curve or if you are computing the integral along the path. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every point in $(x,y) | (0 <= x <= 2) \wedge (0 <= y <= 4)$ is in your plate region.  For example, $x=2, y=1$ is outside the plate.  Thus the answer is not given by 
$$
\int_{x=0}^2\int_{y=0}^4 (x+y)\,dy\,dx = 24
$$
Instead, the way to do this is
$$
\int_{x=0}^2\int_{y=0}^{4-x^2} (x+y)\,dy\,dx = 
\int_{x=0}^2 (x(4-x^2) + \frac12 (4-x^2)^2 )\,dy\,dx\\
= \int_{x=0}^2 (\frac12 x^4 - x^3 - 4x^2 +4x +8) \,dx = \frac{16}5-\frac{16}4-\frac{32}3+\frac{16}2+16=\frac{188}{15}
$$
Unless I did the arithmetic wrong, this still comes out to "none of the above."

Answer (score 0):

The only thing off about your solution is the bounds.

You'l need to integrate over the region: $0\leq x \leq 2$, and $0\leq y \leq 4-x^2$.

In your work you integrate over  $[0,2]\times [0,4]$, which is incorrect.